# When are both the rank and file required for disambiguation of a move in PGN/SAN?

Tags: pgn, notation

The PGN "Standard" (if you want to call it that, because it is very flawed and seems out of date), states:

> - First, if the moving pieces can be distinguished by their originating files, the originating file letter of the moving piece is
>   inserted immediately after the moving piece letter.
> - Second (when the first step fails), if the moving pieces can be distinguished by their originating ranks, the originating rank digit
>   of the moving piece is inserted immediately after the moving piece
>   letter.
> - Third (when both the first and the second steps fail), the two character square coordinate of the originating square of the moving
>   piece is inserted immediately after the moving piece letter.

What I want to know is this: what situation could give rise to the third case?

As I think this through, I cannot for the life of me think up a scenario that the first or second disambiguation rules wouldn't comprehensively cover.

Comment: Does anyone know if the third case every happened in a real game?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible for a piece to need both the rank and file to distinguish it, although it's rare. For example:

```
[FEN "8/1k6/8/8/5Q2/8/3Q1QK1/8 w - - 0 1"]

1.Qf2e3
```

Comment: Incidentally, I once made a chess problem stipulating to play the fastest game leading to such a situation; try to find it!

Comment: @HaukeReddmann I'm sure this is not it, but the fastest one I find is 11 moves, White's moves being 1. e4 2. exd5 3. Nc3 4. d6 5. dxe7 6. exf8N 7. Ne6 8. Ng5 9. Nge2 10. Ng3 11. Ng3e4.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Clear and unambiguous!

Answer (score 7):

@DM showed one possibility, which would also work with bishops (and on various other places on the board, with the three pieces at corners of a square). The only other option is with knights:

```
[FEN "8/1k6/8/8/5N2/8/1N3NK1/8 w - - 0 1"]

1. Nf2d3
```

Comment: The example with knights is best, only one promotion needed.

Comment: Why are knights "the only other option?" Surely it can occur with rooks...

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon no, you need some kind of diagonal movement for this kind of ambiguity.